# Primary problems with authentication process in jcmanager?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

**1:**

[image]

**2:**

[image]

**3:**

[image]

The above pictures attached to the question to ask my questions base on them!

1-As we know and mentioned in **GP Specification**, the card challenge has 8 byte length, but in the first photo, **JCManager** show a six byte card challenge! why?

2-The derivation data that will made based on GP Specification is not equal with the dervation data in JCManager! why?!

3-base on picture **2** , if **static S_ENC** and **static S_MAC** have an equal value,we conclude that the **session S_ENC** and **session S_MAC** must have an equal value. is that right? if yes, why in JCManager there are difference between them?

4-I use this [site](http://www.bierkandt.org/encryption/symmetric_encryption.php) and encrypt the **Derivation data** that highlighted in JCManager by a ECB(DES) encryption, But output is not that expected! and again why!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The card uses SCP02 as indicated in the key information returned for the INITIALIZE UPDATE command. Thus the card challenge has 6 bytes and key derivation data based on a key-specific constant (`01 82` for S_ENC) and the sequence counter (`00 16` as sent by the card in the INITIALIZE UPDATE response). The values you see in JCManager are correct.

The diagrams you are showing do **not** reflect the key derivation mechanism of SCP02. Instead this seems to be the key derivation mechanism for SCP01.

Comment: How I can do INITIALIZE UPDATE and EXTERNAL UPDATE Manually? I mean how I can check verifying of Card cryptogram is OK?